# yii2 browser's back button go back two pages

Tags: php, listview, yii2, back-button

I'm using Yii2's Listview for displaying products and I'm having an issue that I can't solve for a long time.

The flow of my website is like this:

```
Home -> list of products -> product detail
```

In home page, when I click a button, will redirect to "list of products" page, and if I click one of the products then it will redirect me to its detail. While I was in "product detail" page, I click browser's back button and it redirect me to 2 page before (in this case is home page) instead of to "list of products" page. It's as if the "list of products" page is skipped.

What could be the problem? Is this one of Yii2's bugs?

Comment: Are you using Ajax to load the list of products?

Comment: in back button put link of product list page

Comment: @topher yes, I always wrapped the listview with Pjax

Comment: Have the links to product details got `"data-pjax"="0"` attribute? If not add this and check again.